# Monitoring copied file to a usb key

Tags: usb

I'm using USBguard to prevent users from connecting an untrusted device to their machines (Unix).

Once the device is trust, I would like to keep logs of which file is copied to a USB key. I would like to have :

- the username
- the timestamp
- the file name
- the most important for me : the hash of the file

I have looked at AIDE and audit d without much success.

Which tool can I use to do so ?

Thanks

---

## Edit 1

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.1 Jammy Jellyfish

Comment: Hello guivrec, thanks for your answer. I have updated my post but I'm sure to understand why this is information is needed for my question

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. This is a question answer site about currently supported versions of Ubuntu. It was not clear from your original question that the question is about Ubuntu. Answers may not work for other distros or very old versions.

Comment: If you're using Ubuntu 22.04.1, then I suggest you apply security fixes to your system asap, as [this](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/02/24/ubuntu-22-04-2-lts-released/) will show the ISO release of 22.04.2 but installed systems upgraded before that date, and report themselves as Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS currently when fully-upgraded.